# Loop through array to find all objects with matching ids, and merge those objects into one element in the array.

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, lodash

I have an array of objects. Some of the objects have identical ids, but different values in certain keys. What I want to do is loop through the array and find all objects with identical ids, and merge them into one object in the array.

My array looks like this:

```
[{id: 1, letters: [a, b , c] }, {id: 2, letters: [d, e , f] }, {id: 1, letters: [ x, y, z] }]
```

The outcome I want is an array that looks like this:

```
[{id: 1, letters: [a, b , c, x, y, z] }, {id: 2, letters: [d, e , f] }]
```

I'm using lodash, but just can't quite seem to get it

Comment: Can you show us the code that you tried?

Comment: I think you're looking for _.groupBy()

Comment: That outcome is not what you explained above. Those id's are not identical. (1 and 2)?

Comment: @EngineerDollery the code I used was to instead of an array create an object with keys that are essentially the objects you see in the array. Then I checked if that key already existed and if it did, I used a _.merge for the two objects. This worked, but i'm working with some legacy code and changing that array into an object broke some stuff (not trying to do that).

Comment: @NiCkNewman the second array is the outcome I want. But if you look at the first array you can see two objects with the id 1, which I want to be merged into one object in the outcome array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this (that's underscore.js, but I believe lodash is very similar)

```
data = [{id: 1, letters: ['a', 'b', 'c'] }, {id: 2, letters: ['d', 'e', 'f'] }, {id: 1, letters: ['x', 'y', 'z'] }]

groups = _.groupBy(data, function(obj) { return obj.id })
results = _.map(groups, function(groups) {
  id = groups[0].id;
  letters = _.chain(groups).map(function(obj) { return obj.letters }).flatten().uniq().value()
  return {id: id, letters: letters }
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(results))
// [{"id":1,"letters":["a","b","c","x","y","z"]},{"id":2,"letters":["d","e","f"]}]
```